# How do I use Owin Katana Logger

Tags: asp.net, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I see in files like this within the Microsoft Owin projects a logger is being called

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs

Can anyone tell me how I activate it to actually start writing logs somewhere that I can read?

Answer (score 7):

By default Katana uses the TraceSource mechanism in .NET for logging. Add the following snippet to your config file to enable logging to a file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />

  <sources>
    <source name="Microsoft.Owin">
      <listeners>
        <add name="KatanaListener" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>

  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="KatanaListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="katana.trace.log"
          traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
  </sharedListeners>

  <switches>
    <add name="Microsoft.Owin"
          value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

You can use Katana's default logging infrastructure and modify as needed. Here is a [very detailed post](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/logging-in-the-owin-world-with-microsoft-owin--introduction) that explains Katana's logging infrastructure and outlines how to add Owin/Katana logging to your projects. It also contains [Github samples](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/OwinSamples/tree/master/LoggingSample) that you can reference.

This [official Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana) is very helpful as well.