# Sustainsys.Saml2 OWIN access_denied and logging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, sustainsys-saml2

When /Saml2/Acs from the middleware redirects to ExternalLoginCallback I'm getting an error=access_denied as part of the url.  From searches I've done, I need to enable logging and I'll be able to find the reason.  The problem is I cannot figure out how to enable logging to a file so that I'm able to read it.

The [Troubleshooting page](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/troubleshooting.html) says to connect an ILoggerAdapater to my SPOptions.Logger, but that if I'm using OWIN middleware it is done automatically and I can see the output in the OWIN/Katana logging - Is this log in a file somewhere/can I make it show up in a file so that I'm able to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Owin Middleware by defaults wires up a `ILoggerAdapter` that writes to the Owin/Katana logging system. To get that output to a file, you need to configure Katana logging. There's an SO post describing what to do: [How do I use Owin Katana Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283208/how-do-i-use-owin-katana-logger)

Another option is to replace the existing `ILoggerAdapter` with your own write-to-file logic.

Comment: Thank you! I am now getting the log file, time to start debugging the actual issue.